# Rails 3: "Schema migrations table does not exists yet"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

So some months ago, for some reason I got a weird git message and was afraid to deploy. So I started making changes to the production application directly and trying to also manually make the same changes to my local code.

So now the time came to update everything, I wanted to sync my local code with the production code and start using git and capistrano to deploy again. So I downloaded the code from the production server and copy pasted some files into my local code to make sure I wasn't going to overwrite anything on the production server.

I'm now able to run `cap:deploy` and everything seems to work as expected. Problem is, I created a new column on my dev copy and I was about to run `cap deploy:migrate` but I'm afraid it's going to wipe out my production database.

So I ran `rake db:migrate:status` and I get the message `Schema migrations table does not exists yet.` I already checked my production database and the schema migrations table IS there. So it seems the app is not recognizing my current migration version and I'm afraid that if I run `cap deploy:migrate` is going to run ALL the migrations and wipe out my database.

Why am I getting this message? What should I do?

Comment: I have a similar problem... the stackoverflow crickets seem to be chirping for both of us.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using a sqlite db?

Answer (score 4):

My situation may be somewhat different from you but I too got the same message.
I was in development in my local PC with Rails 4.

Try using only **db:migrate**.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found is to use abort_if_pending_migrations:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production; bundle exec rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations
```

This seems to print nothing if your migrations are up-to-date, and list tables that need updating if they are not. This is with Rails 4.1.8.